# Java Image Point To Mouse

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm having a problem where an image rotates based on the difference between the players position and the mouse position which works but the image isn't actually pointing at the mouse. I want the top center of the image to be pointing at the mouse and it just seems that the angle is always off. I'll post the code below.

```
  Input input = gc.getInput();

  if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W))
  {
     position.y -= 3;
  }

  if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A))
  {
     position.x -= 3;
  }

  if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S))
  {
     position.y += 3;
  }

  if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D))
  {
     position.x += 3;
  }

  float xDistance = input.getAbsoluteMouseX() - position.x;
  float yDistance = input.getAbsoluteMouseY() - position.y;
  double angleToTurn = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance));
  entityImage.setRotation((float) angleToTurn);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) What do you mean by 'off'?  What are some desired & expected results?

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for [Math.atan(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan%28double%29) says that the returning value can range from -pi/2 to pi/2.
So you need to compensate for that return value.

```
double angleToTurn = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance));
if(angleToTurn < 0)
{
        angleToTurn += 360;
}
```